# How to fix "Unmappable character for encoding windows-1252 error" displayed by Gradle build?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When building my project in Android Studio by executing the Gradle release task, I get the following error:

```
error: unmappable character for encoding windows-1252
 * usage: app:behavior_saveFlags=ÔÇ?hideable|skipCollapsedÔÇ?
                                                            ^
```

It doesn't break the build or doesn't seem to cause any bugs so far from what I know of, however I would like to find out what's causing this issue.

The error seems to be triggered by some of the generated comment blocks in R.java:

```
/**
 * Behavior properties will be saved and restored by evaluating each flag.
 * usage: app:behavior_saveFlags=”hideable|skipCollapsed”
 * <p>Must be one or more (separated by '|') of the following constant values.</p>
```

**My configuration:**

- Android Studio 3.4
- Gradle Tools 3.4.0
- Gradle 5.4.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a config for encoding in the android compileOptions in your `build.gradle`

Look for encoding = 'Cp1252' and remove it.

```
android
{
    compileOptions {
        encoding = 'Cp1252'
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. The solution was as simple as replacing the project encoding with UTF-8.  It looks like someone set this to Cp1252 for some obscure reason in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's [attrs.xml](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/edit/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/res/values/attrs.xml), which reads `encoding="utf-8"`.

Change all files of the project [to UTF-8 encoding](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/); some file might be `Windows-1252` encoded.